# Unable to get into server via putty WHM and cpanel locked

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I have a Linux 6.2 vps with a cpanel. I think possibly that i have been the subject of a brute force attack that has locked me out.  I am trying to access my root server via putty but cannot do this because I am getting this error  No support authentication methods available-server sent public key gssapi-keyex gssapi with mic. So I cannot get in via Cpanel or the root server HELP.

Comment: Do you have any servers with this cPanel machine logged in as root?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any servers logged in for that cPanel server as root or try to login as root(to that cPanel server) from a different machine. Then, this doc can help further!

[BruteForce](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/help-i-have-been-locked-out-brute-force-sistem-112341.html)